# Adding existing contacts to outlook distribution list in Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, distribution-list

I want to use python to add contacts to an existing distribution list (DL). I am using below code which stores the member's email address of the DL to an array. I am able to achieve this by the below code.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
address_lists = outlook.AddressLists
dls = address_lists['Global Address List']
contact = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(2)

contacts = dls.AddressEntries.Item('DL Data').Members
group_mail_list = []

for c in contacts:
    # print(c)
    group_mail_list.append(c.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.lower())
group_mail_list
```

I am not sure how to add contact to the DL. For example, I want to add the contact 'test1@company.com' which already exists in the address book but this contact is not a member of the 'DL Data'. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: A note on efficiency ... call `app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')` and then re-use that: `outlook = app.GetNamespace('MAPI')` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can't easily do that using Outlook Object Model - `DistListItem` only exposes `AddMember`/`AddMembers` methods, which take a `Recipient` or `Recipients` objects respectively. This means you can only pass `Recipients` collection from an existing message (`MailItem.Recipients`) or from an address book dialog (`SelectNamesDialog.Recipients` collection). You can also create a temporary recipient using `Namespace.CreateRecipient` and then resolve it (`Recipient.Resolve`), but that means Outlook should be able to resolve the name passed to `Namespace.CreateRecipient` - the entry must be visible to the address book and it should be unique (recipient won't be resolved if the name ambiguous).

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDODistListItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDODistListItem.htm).`AddContact` method, which can take either a contact or another distribution list.

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you have a working code or an example that I can use for the DistListItem with SelectNamesDialog.Recipients? My company is not willing to purchase any third party applications.

Comment: See the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selectnamesdialog . You can easily extend it for use with `DistListItem`